# Definition of isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V_1$ is a vector space over the field $K_1$ and $V_2$ is a vector space over the field $K_2$. What is the definition of an isomorphism between these two vector spaces?

My best guess would be that $K_1$ and $K_2$ have to be isomorphic as fields. Say $\xi:K_1\to K_2$ is an isomorphism. And furthermore, we must have a bijective function $\sigma:V_1 \to V_2$ with

$$\sigma(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2) = \xi(\lambda)\sigma(v_1) + \xi(\mu)\sigma(v_2)$$ for all $v_1,v_2 \in V_1$ and all $\lambda, \mu \in K_1$.

Is this correct, or have I missed or added extra conditions?

Comment: It seems correct but silly to consider different but isomorphic scalar fields.

Comment: I have never encountered a notion of isomorphism of vector spaces over different fields. However, I agree that this is a good definition (and essentially the case you are considering does not use two different fields).
Why would you want to use two different base fields?

Comment: Is it possible to have two vector spaces be isomorphic if their underlying fields are NOT isomorphic?

Comment: No, unless you want to introduce this notion yourself.

Comment: @nullUser It wouldn't make any sense. One of the best properties of vector spaces is that they are classified (up to isomorphism) by their dimension, making a given vector space isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of your base field. Different base fields would give you different decompositions of your vector space...?

Comment: @MTurgeon: Just note that $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ and over $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ has the same dimension, and the identity is surely an isomorphism. (However I am cheating here, because we usually require the field to be somehow fixed in the language, as endomorphisms of the vector space, and in this aspect the structures on $\mathbb R$ are **not** isomorphic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know what it means for a definition to be correct. Certainly this is a sensible definition (e.g. it defines an "equivalence relation" on the "set" of vector spaces). It is the notion of isomorphism that one gets in the following [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory): objects are pairs $(k, V)$ of a field and a vector space over that field, and morphisms are pairs $(\phi, T)$ of field morphisms $\phi : k_1 \to k_2$ and maps $T : V_1 \to V_2$ such that
$$T(av + bw) = \phi(a) T(v) + \phi(b) T(w).$$

However, when most people talk about isomorphism of vector spaces, they almost always work implicitly with a fixed base field $k$. This means more than that $k_1, k_2$ are isomorphic; it means that we have fixed an isomorphism between them.

Comment: One reason to restrict to the case of a fixed field is that it makes $k$-vector spaces into algebras (in the sense of universal algebra), with one unary operation for every scalar in the field, and the category of $k$-vector spaces into a variety (with all that this entails).

Comment: @Qiaochu: The category you describe is a reasonably interesting category. It can be obtained by applying the Grothendieck construction to the strict (!) 2-functor $\textbf{Vect}(-) : \textbf{Fld}^\textrm{op} \to \mathfrak{Cat}$, and is thus a fibred category over $\textbf{Fld}$. It's a sub-fibred-category of the stack of quasicoherent sheaves over the category of schemes...